# Looping file contents in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file /tmp/a.txt whose contents I want to read in a variable many number of times. If the EOF is reached then it should start from the beginning.

i.e. If the contents of the file is "abc" and I want to get 10 chars, it should be "abcabcabca".

For this I wrote an obvious script:

```
while [ 1 ]; 
  do cat /tmp/a.txt; 
done | 
for i in {1..3}; 
  do read -N 10 A; 
  echo "For $i: $A"; 
done
```

The only problem is that it hangs! I have no idea why it does so!

I am also open to other solutions in bash.

Comment: It hangs because you ask it to do only 3 times (1..3) a "read -N 10 A" on the output of /tmp/a.txt.
What are you trying to do?

Comment: `cat file file file file...>newfile`  will duplicate the file contents. well if you need duplicate the file 1m times, cat won't work. what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: while loop and for loop are piped, so the output of while is passed to for. Since for loop exits after 3 iterations, I assume while loop should get something like SIGPIPE and exit. But it doesn't. The output comes and it then hangs there.

Comment: @Kent I am trying to read contents of a file into a variable, many number of times. The length of the content could be more than length of the file, in which case it should get characters from the beginning of the file.

Comment: That much is obvious, but it's not obvious (to me at least) what sort of real-world problem would require this sort of a solution.  What are you trying to achieve?  Perhaps it could be done by other means.

Comment: ok, its quite simple actually. I want to load my database with realistic human-generated data. It contains a lot of fields with varying sizes, which I want to read from a big file (like a story textbook).

Comment: say you want to get `x` characters, first get the length of the file (`n`), then loop the print/output file content `x/n` times. and append the `x%n` characters from the file (or stored variable)

Answer (score 1):

To repeat over and over a line you can :

```
yes "abc" | for i in {1..3}; do read -N 10 A; echo "for $i: $A"; done
```

yes will output 'forever', but then the for i in 1..3 will only execute the "do ... done;" part 3 times

yes add a "\n" after the string. If you don't want it, do:

```
 yes "abc" | tr -d '\n' | for i in {1..3}; do read -N 10 A; echo "for $i: $A"; done
```

In all the above, note that as the read is after a pipe, in bash it will be in a subshell, so "$A" will only available in the "do....done;" area, and be lost after!

To loop and read from a file, and also not do that in a subshell:

```
for i in {1..3}; do read -N 10 A ; echo "for $i: $A"; done <$(cat /the/file)
```

To be sure there is enough data in /the/file, repeat at will:

```
for i in {1..3}; do read -N 10 A ; echo "for $i: $A"; done <$(cat /the/file /the/file /the/file)
```

To test the latest:  echo -n "abc" > /the/file  (-n, so there is no trainling newline)

Comment: I would like to use contents of a file (and the file is very big) rather than hardcoding the string. yes is also adding a trailing newline which i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

The script hangs because of the first loop. After the three iterations of the second loop (for) are done, the first loop repeatedly starts new `cat` instances which read the file and then write the content `abc` to the pipe. The write to the pipe doesn't work any more in the later iterations. Yes, there is a SIGPIPE kill, but to the `cat` command and not to the loop itself. So the solution is to catch the error in the right place:

```
while [ 1 ]; 
  do cat /tmp/a.txt || break
done | 
for i in {1..3}; 
  do read -N 10 A; 
  echo "For $i: $A"; 
done
```

Besides: output is following:

```
For 1: abcabcabca
For 2: bcabcabcab
For 3: cabcabcabc
<-- (Here the shell hangs no more)
```